# How to Interpolate a 3D MeshRegion?

Tags: regions, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh

If you were given some discrete `MeshRegion` called `r` (you don't know `R`):

```
R = ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y z + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 z + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 z + 
     y^6 + z^6 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
r = DiscretizeGraphics @ RegionPlot3D[R, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.6, 1.6}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False]
```

What would be a good way to interpolate `R`, the underlying continuous equational or functional representation? That is, how can you convert a given `MeshRegion` to an `ImplicitRegion` or `ParametricRegion`?

Comment: Do you know anything about R? Anything about its form? Or just have r?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very simple method is by interpolating the signed distance function (`SignedRegionDistance`) of a `BoundaryMeshRegion`. Therefore, I use `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` instead of `DiscretizeGraphics` to produce a `BoundaryMeshRegion` called `S`. Afterwards, I sample `SignedRegionDistance` on a regular grid surrounding `S` and apply `Interpolation`. This uses bi-cubic splines per default. Of course any other interpolation/approximation technique can be used, for example, trigonometric polynomials, radial basis functions etc.

```
S = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   RegionPlot3D[R, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.6, 1.6}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False];

box = List @@ BoundingRegion[S];
center = Mean[box];
scale = 1.5;
B = Cuboid @@ ({center, center} + scale (box - {center, center}));
n = 20;
nodes = Tuples[Subdivide[#[[1]], #[[2]], n] & /@ Transpose[List @@ B]];
df = SignedRegionDistance[S];
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{nodes, df[nodes]}]];

Show[
 S,
 SliceContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z], "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} \[Element] B]
 ]
```

[image]

And here is a contourplot of the interpolated signed distance function:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 f[x, y, z] == 0, 
 {x, B[[1, 1]], B[[2, 1]]}, {y, B[[1, 2]], B[[2, 2]]}, {z, B[[1, 3]], B[[2, 3]]}
 ]
```

[image]

A rediscretized region looks like this:

```
R1 = ImplicitRegion[
   f[x, y, z] <= 0, 
   {{x, B[[1, 1]], B[[2, 1]]}, {y, B[[1, 2]], B[[2, 2]]}, {z, B[[1, 3]], B[[2, 3]]}}
   ];
S1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R1, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.1}];
GraphicsRow[{Show[S], Show[S1]}]
```

[image]

(left: original region; right: rediscretized region)

Comment: Can you compute a closed form for the normal to the surface at a point?

Comment: Well, the normal at a point of a levelset is just the normalized gradient (times $1$ or $-1$, depending on inwards/outwards pointing).  I guess `normal = {x, y, z} \[Function] Evaluate[
    D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 1}]/
     Sqrt[D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 1}].D[
        f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 1}]]
    ];` would do.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Only knowing `r` I Tried `RegionPlot3D[RegionDistance[r, {x, y, z}] == 0 , 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.6, 1.6}}]` to approximate `R` directly, but Mathematica doesn't evaluate output. What's wrong with this idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Ulrich There are several problems with this. I) `RegionPlot3D` is better at plotting volumetric regions. Thus it should better applied to inequalities. E.g., `df = RegionDistance[r];
RegionPlot3D[
 df[{x, y, z}] <= .1, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.6, 1.6}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]` works. II) `RegionPlot3D[
 df[{x, y, z}] <= 0., {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.6, 1.6}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]` does not work because the volume is actually a surface and hence has 3-dim Hausdorff measure 0. Hence it is hard to detect numerically.

Comment: The latter tends to happen with all minimizing sets of functions. Another issue is that `RegionDistance[r]` is not differentiable at the levelset in question. With a signed-distance function, Newton's method is available because the signed distance function (of a smooth embedded hyper-surface) i) is differentiable and ii) has surjective differential (both in a neighborhood of the surface).

Comment: Btw.: `SignedRegionDistance[r]` would not help much. One first has to convert to a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, for example with `SignedRegionDistance[
 BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[r], MeshCells[r, 2]]]`.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you for the clear  explanation, now I got it (hopefully). I was thinking about a solution which keeps the `mesh r` for interpolation by using `Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex ` for a fast decision `point on r` but didn't succeed...

Answer (score 3):

In my attempt I try to realize a very simple signed distance function which only needs information about the meshregion `r`(assumption: triangle mesh in space)

```
points = MeshCoordinates[ r]  ;
elements = MeshCells[r, 2]  ; (* all triangle elements *) 
triangles = elements /. Polygon -> List // Flatten[#, 1] &;(* node indices*)
```

Furthermore I use/presume  a function, which detects the nearest element of a given point.

```
mnc = Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[r ] 
(*mnc[x,y,z] evaluates the index of nearest element*)
```

The following interpolation idea doesn't need an embedding grid, uses only the given nodes and calculates  the signed distance in normal element direction.
Because it only considers the nearest element it's some kind of one dimensional interpolation

```
fUN[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Block[{n\[CapitalDelta], no, p1, p2,p3},
n\[CapitalDelta] = mnc[{x, y, z}][[2]];  (*nearest triangle element *)
{p1, p2, p3} = punkte[[dreiecke[[n\[CapitalDelta] ]]]];(* triangle points*)
no = Cross[p2 - p1, p3 - p1 ];(* normal vector triangle *)
no.({x, y, z} - p1)(* normal distance*)
```

]

If `fUN` returns zero the point `x,y,z` is element of the  triangle plane.

```
RUN = ImplicitRegion[fUN[x, y, z] == 0, {{x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.6,1.6}}] (* interpolated region R*)

DiscretizeRegion[RUN]
```

[image]

The program seems to work quite well (no idea where the sliver comes from...)

Function `fUN` might be improved checking `x,y,z inside triangle` and using compile!